# Lua Returns the result of executing as string

Tags: lua, executable, vala

I use luaVM in another programming language (Vala) and want to pass the code from vala to lua so that lua returns the result of executing this code as a string.

```
> s2="print (5+5)"
> s2
print (5+5)
> loadstring(s2)
function: 0x55834153f080
> func = loadstring(s2)
> func()
10
```

tried a lot of things, but I did not succeed, that is, I need instead of 10 was a variable of type string containing 10. So I could do vm.to_string(-1) of Vala and to obtain "10"

Comment: Try `return tostring(5+5)`

Comment: Remember that you can also call the code in one line with `local str = loadstring(s2)()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Egor stated you can cast your result to a string before returning it using `tostring`.

I would also add you may want to use `dostring` not `loadstring`.

A `load` function in lua means to compile and **not run** the chunk, instead it returns a function when called will run the chunk.(`loadfile`, `loadstring`)

A `do` function will compile and run the contents.(`dofile`, `dostring`)

The details can be found here: [Lua: 8 – Compilation, Execution, and Errors](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html)

> Like dofile, loadfile also loads a Lua chunk from a file, but it does not run the chunk. Instead, it only compiles the chunk and returns the compiled chunk as a function.

This section speak more directly to `loadfile` but the page covers `loadstring`.

---

if `dostring` is not defined it can be like so:

```
function dostring(s)
    return assert(loadstring(s))()
end
```

---

If you are using a version of lua later then 5.1 `loadstring` becomes `load`

Comment: I think I need to share the code for better understanding. The interface consists of 2 TextView. On the idea you write lua code on the right and see the result on the left. But now the result of the execution is displayed in the console, and on the right only: 

[string "print (5..."]:2: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 1) near <eof> 

https://pastebin.com/uhQhR0vT

Comment: It seems as if now the last element of string in vm is its errors when the string has not yet been entered to the end. And the correct result of execution gets to the console. I think this is so because on the left it is impossible to see the error associated with the input print(5), (because it is not an error). There either "[string " print (5..."]: 2:') ' expected (to close '(' at line 1" or "[string "print (5))..."]: 2:') 'unexpected symbol near ')'"

Comment: line 49 `return tostring dostring("..inputCode..")` should look something like this `return tostring(dostring("..inputCode..") or 'nil')`. you are missing `()` from your `tostring` function around the `dostring`

Comment: `dostring("..inputCode..") or 'nil'` the or `nil` returns a default value to the tostring function if the `inputCode` does not return a value. This will prevent an errors from tostring when this happens. the value could be anything it does not need to be `nil` it could be `0` if that is better

Comment: All still the same, recorded a short screencast of how it looks.
https://youtu.be/2SvNORmAu7A

Comment: Looks like the error is just not being cleared from the console. As you type the code in, like `print(5)`, once it becomes a valid Lua statement the error stays as the last error state which is `[string "print (5..."]:1: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 1) near <eof>` because the last char you added is `)`. I would suggest either clearing the view before each run of the editor code or enforcing some kind of run command so that the partially typed code does not run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186369/discussion-between-nifim-and-gavr).